# Does the cross over the projection graphic indicate the origin of the projection? [QGIS]

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, well-known-text

I am using a projection that I have defined from a WKT format, and not included in QGIS' default roster of projections. See below in the image. The origin of my projection is 40N and 100W. Why is the cross hair centring where it is? Or is this just a generic default that occurs when you define your own custom projection in Q?

[image]

Comment: There isn't any useful information in your image, but I doubt the center of the graphic box is the center.

Answer (score 1):

The cross simply indicates where your map canvas is centered right now and the violet box shows you the current extent of the map canvas. Normally, there should be a second, light red box that shows the extent the selected CRS is valid for.

*Screenshot: zoomed to Europe, the small violet box shows the extent of the map canvas (=red outlined frame), including the point the canvas is centered on, somewhere in eastern Poland/western Ukraine. The red box covers the whole world, because I selected EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator) in the CRS dialog window.*
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "map canvas". But no matter where I zoom to in the world, no matter which layers are selected to be shown/not shown, and no matter which CRS I inspect, the cross hair is displayed at [Null Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island). I also tried deleting OpenStreetMap layer which is the only layer in my project that covers anything outside Europe. Using 3.10.4-A Coruña.

Comment: Map canvas is standard QGIS terminology, see: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/mapviewnavigation.html and https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/589b8f25440243327fa7a23a/1519345702901-P16JJPGMOBZZKYIDIDFX/QGIS3red.jpg?format=1000w

Comment: @Mads Skjern Can you show us a screenshot like mine above, where your map is zoomed to some place like Europe with the crosshair still on NULL island?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/UwGYRt6.png. Zoomed in on Denmark, purple crosshair at Null Island. Ok?

Comment: Can't reproduce this behaviour, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B51vp.jpg Thus difficult to say what goes wrong in your case. You might ask a new question for that, refering to this one here to say that this solution does not work for you.